# Multiplying an answer (greater than) in SQL query

Tags: sql

I am busy trying to finish a question for a project i'm doing and for the life of me I am stumped.

The question is as follows:
*Roxanne has been told to bill clients ZAR5 a day for every movie that is overdue. Write the SQL query that will include a column with the overdue amount in tblRentals, and display the report.*

I have tried a few things but im pretty new to SQL and have not found a way to solve it. Here is the code i've tried using, but it doesn't create a new column or display the amount * 5 for each overdue movie.. Please help!!

```
    SELECT CustomerID, DateReturned, DueDate
    From tblRentals
    WHERE
    ((DateReturned>DueDate)*5) AS OverdueAmount
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: I wouldn't even expect that to be accepted syntactically in whatever unknown RDBMS you are using. Anyway, protips: Things you want to see go in the `select` clause. Things you want to filter go in the `where` clause. I guess here, the alias in the `where` clause is treated as a boolean whenever the result is not `0`, but the calculation is wrong, & anyway, of course you don't `select` it, so you don't see it. The expression does not make any sense. SQL needs to be told exactly what it has to calculate; you're just giving a bunch of things contextually convertible to bool & hoping for the best.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really am new to this so all feedback is appreciated. I'm using MS Access, could you possible suggest any fixes to my code? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For Oracle:

```
SELECT 
    CustomerID, 
    DateReturned, 
    DueDate, 
    (DateReturned - DueDate)*5 as OverdueAmount
From 
    tblRentals
WHERE
    DateReturned > DueDate and DateReturned Is NoT Null
```

For MySQL: 
Change `(DateReturned - DueDate)*5` to `DATEDIFF(DateReturned, DueDate)*5`

Comment: There's no `-` in `DATEDIFF`: It's `DATEDIFF(DateReturned , DueDate)`

Comment: This shows the requested report, but doesn't add the column to table tblRentals. For that, use 'ALTER TABLE tblRentals ADD COLUMN....'. And include a table trigger to automatically fill in the value.

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much for your suggestion. I am using MS Access, could you possibly help me to correct the code for MS Access?

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly the answer I was looking for. I can see exactly where I went wrong. Thank you again. Regards, Tristan.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it suffice your requirement.